# Is there a non-trivial real linear operator space that is conjugative to the complex space and closed under multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

A real vector space W is "conjugative" to a complex vector space V if $W \subseteq V$ and for all $v \in V$ there is a unique representation $v = w_1 + iw_2, w_{1,2} \in W$

This is equivalent to every basis of W being also a basis of V. So for $C^n$, $R^n$ is a conjugative subspace but many others exist. Any basis for $C^n$ will form a conjugative subspace if you take its span over the reals.

I am interested in conjugative subspaces for linear operators that are also closed under multiplication. For $L(C^n)$, the space of linear operators over $C^n$, $L(R^n)$ is one, but I am not sure how to approach the question of whether there are any others.

This is motivated from thinking about the self-adjoints space, which is conjugative but not closed under multiplication.

Comment: You say any basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ gives a conjugative subspace by taking the span over reals, but why stop at $\mathbb{C}^n$? This should work for every complex vector space including $L(\mathbb{C}^n)$, or am I missing something?

Comment: No you're not, you can create conjugating subspaces like that, but they're mostly not closed under multiplication. I am looking for one that is closed and is not the trivial $L(R^n)$.